# Is there a configurable failure mechanism that can throw an exception if nodes go down from grid?

Tags: gridgain, ignite

Gridgain has failover spi mechanism for failure of jobs on nodes.
However, we would like to configure a failure mechanism that throws exception even when once of the configured data nodes goes down.

How can we do this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to prevent failover for your tasks and throw an exception if a node that was in process of executing a job fails? (I'm not sure I understood you correctly, so please correct me if I'm wrong)

If I'm right, the easiest way is to configure `NeverFailoverSpi`, like this:

```
<bean id="ignite.cfg" class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
    ...
    <property name="failoverSpi">
        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.failover.never.NeverFailoverSpi"/>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Another option is to use `IgniteCompute.withAsyncNoFailover()` method. It's useful if you want to disable failover for a small subset of tasks, but still use default mechanisms for others. Here is an example:

```
IgniteCompute compute = ignite.compute().withAsyncNoFailover();

// Tasks executed with this compute instance will never failover.
compute.execute(MyTask1.class, "arg");
```